# Why a checkbox in a gridview doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, checkbox

I am binding a checkbox in gridview with a database field, which stores boolean value i.e. IsRejected. I am trying to make it real time, i.e. if i tick checkbox then it should put 1 in database or 0 , i have tried but no effect. Why ?

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdvwRejectedEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
                                             DataKeyNames="EdrID" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped  table-bordered"
                                             AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">

                                          <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EdrID" HeaderText="Edr ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployerName" HeaderText="Employer" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="Branch" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeUniqueID" HeaderText="EmployeeUniqueID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Employee Name" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PayStartDate" HeaderText="Pay Start Date" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PayEndDate" HeaderText="Pay End Date" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxIsRejection" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IsRejected") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="IsRejected" HeaderText="Is Rejected" />--%>
                                          </Columns>

                                        </asp:GridView>
                                            </div>
                                        </ContentTemplate>

                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
        {

            if (Session["UserCredential"] != null)
            {
                ClsSystemUser user = (ClsSystemUser)Session["UserCredential"];
                ClsSystemUser obj = new ClsSystemUser();
                obj = obj.GetOrganizationName(user.Type_ID, user.OfficeID, user.SystemUserID);

                int usertypeid = user.Type_ID;


                if (usertypeid == 3)
                {
                    //UserTypeID.Text = "Branch";

                    ClsRejectedFiles RejFiles = new ClsRejectedFiles();
                    grdvwRejectedEmployees.DataSource = RejFiles.GetRejectedFiles("30411098037111", 3, 1);
                    grdvwRejectedEmployees.DataBind();

                }
```

like if i tick or untick the checkbox then it doesn't affect the values in database, i.e. if i check then i should put 1 in database IsRejected column or 0 if i uncheck

Comment: Set the Checkbox's `Checked` property with your datafield. You are setting the Text property .

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `Text` property of the Checkbox with the data field value try setting the `Checked` property so it will set the checkbox value.

```
   <asp:CheckBox 
      ID="chkBoxIsRejection" runat="server" HeaderText="IsRejection" 
      Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsRejected")) %>'/>
```

---

**UPDATE**

As OP wanted to update the database on checkbox check chagned. For doing that you need to add the event to tell the page how to react when the checkbox checked changed

You need to add the event `CheckedChanged`. [You can read it here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
      <asp:CheckBox 
      ID="chkBoxIsRejection" runat="server" HeaderText="IsRejection" 
      Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsRejected")) %>'
      AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
```

And then in code behind

```
     protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           // write code to save the changes to the database.
     }
```

Comment: doesn't work , same issue but atleast it represents real value, but doesn't work real time

Comment: like if i tick or untick the checkbox then it doesn't affect the values in database, i.e. if i check then i should put 1 in database IsRejected column or 0 if i uncheck